# Android-RESTful Services

Tags: android, rest

I have started working on a university project. I have to test various REST frameworks for Android and see which one is the most efficient/stable currently.

Which are most popular REST frameworks currently for Android? I have heard about Spring.

Secondly, how do you create a RESTful service for Android?

Comment: Better to ask your professor.

Comment: you shouldn't use this forum to ask how to perform specific works. Instead, elaborate your question in a techinical maner: i.e.: What are the best android REST frameworks? Just do a quicky search in google for this and I'm sure you'll find more than 4 frameworks. I can tell you aout two: Spring and Volley.

Comment: "_There are 4 frameworks and tools to be tested._" - I presume he's given you a list, because, no, there's more than 4. Maybe ask ? I'd start by comparing features, performance, and so on. But this question is too broad for Stack Overflow, so you're unlikely to get a useful answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a number of REST libraries that do more or less for you. Arguably, the most popular for Android are Retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit) and my personal favourite RoboSpice (https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) for two simple reasons: runs as a service and works alongside Activity lifecycle.

Answering which one is the best would start a flame war.

Keep in mind that ANY library that can do a HTTP request with POST and GET can be "weaponised" as RESTful library, it's only a matter of how much boilerplate you want to write on your own and how much control over each aspect you require.